# laravel groupBy and sum field with multiple relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-9, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to get the relationships that are associated with the productions table it has a job which is a one to many relationship, a part which is also a one to many and a materials that is a many to many. I then want to group the items in the productions table by the part_id and sum the quantity field in the productions table.

This gets me close by it only eager loads the parts table relationship and not the materials or job. materials returns and empty collection and jobs is null

```
$data = Production::with('part', 'materials', 'job')
        ->join('parts', 'part_id', '=', 'parts.id')
        ->join('jobs', 'job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
        ->where('job_id', '=', $job->id)
        ->groupBy('part_id')
        ->selectRaw('part_id, SUM(quantity) as total, part_id')
        ->get();
```

here is my material relationship in productions

```
/**
     * Get the materials that this production is made of.
     */
    public function materials(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Material::class, 'material_production')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

and the productions relationship to materials

```
     /**
     * Get the production that used this material
     */
    public function production(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Production::class, 'material_production')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

and the productions relationship to jobs

```
    /**
     * Get the job type of this production.
     */
    public function job()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Job::class);
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can get this to work if I remove database strict and set it to false so I am guessing that I will need to query this using DB:raw

this is the gitlab link for the repo[gitlab](https://gitlab.com/useless3ngineer/bizops)

I did just have the realization the reason the other tables don't load is because their is no key in the groupBy for them since it creates its own collection

Answer (score 0):

@Samiran thank you. You got me on the right track this seems to do what I was hoping just have to join the pivot table and the materials table to grab the relationship and use the `job_id` in the select like this:

```
$data = Production::with('part', 'materials', 'job')
    ->join('jobs', 'job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
    ->join('parts', 'part_id', '=', 'parts.id')
    ->join('material_production', 'productions.id', '=', 'production_id')
    ->join('materials', 'material_production.material_id', '=','materials.id')
    ->where('job_id', '=', $job->id)
    ->groupBy('part_id', 'materials.id', 'job_id')
    ->selectRaw('part_id, job_id, materials.id, SUM(quantity) as total')
    ->get();
```